# I have an issue with my browser loading CSS I'm not sure what to do

Tags: c#, visual-studio, browser

Ok, so I'm making a browser in Winforms C# using Visual Studio 2019 and I've noticed when loading certain websites with more advanced UI it will either, look very weird or not load at all. I'm not sure why this is.
[image: Screenshot]

also this is my first question on stack over flow so I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: Welcome, @Wumpus. When posting, it would be nice if you could post some code that reproduces your issue. As it is, we have to guess which browser component you're using and how you set it up, which makes it difficult to help you unless we've seen your exact issue before.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question)

Comment: A webpage can be designed to work with different browsers.  You can add a http header to your request to specify the browser.  See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

Comment: The question is quite vague. It assumes the reader is familiar with your implementation and it does not provide any details to work with. Please consider editing your question and providing code samples and details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the WebBrowser control is that by default it renders output in IE7 rendering mode.
I also reproduced your problem.
[image]

Internet Explorer 7 rendering will be used if you do not override the Feature Browser Emultate setting in the registry.

Open the registry, I used the key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

> For your user (Current User) only use this key:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet
> Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
>
> For all users on the computer/server use this key:
>
> On 64 bit app on 64 bit- or 32 bit app on 32 bit machine:
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet
> Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
>
> On 32 bit app on 64 bit machine:
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet
> Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
>
> **Value:**
>
> **11001 (0x2AF9)** Internet Explorer 11. Webpages are displayed in IE11 edge mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.
>
> **9999 (0x270F)** Windows Internet Explorer 9. Webpages are displayed in IE9 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.

Because my executable is named browserloadingcss.exe, I add an DWORD entry with the Name browserloadingcss.exe and with a value 11001 (to use Internet Exlporer 11-rendering).
I also tried tried to set the value 9999 and it can render normally.
[image]

Then I ran my program and got the following result graph:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Your issue can be occurring from wrong url of css file while importing in winforms.
Please check url if issue persists then share some code so that we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: It does not really answer the question. It should be a comment, not a an anwser.